# Split sentence into array of letters then add letter in between

Tags: php, arrays, unicode

I want to split a word or small sentence into an array so that each letter is part of the array, but I also want to add a character in between each letter then output it back into a string.
The character I want to use is a Unicode character, U+0336 combining long stroke overlay or " ̶ ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but something like:

```
$str = "I am a test string";
$chars = preg_split('//', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$dash_separated = implode("-", $chars);
```

Comment: You interchange `$chars` and `$pieces`. And loading the Regular expression engine seems to me to be a bit too much overhead for such a simple task.

Comment: It isnt a dash. Thanks though, here is the finished result ;)
http://herp.in/strike.php

Answer (score 1):

use [str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) (or [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).